# How to extract null check into method and get valid null type checking?

Tags: typescript

This assumes strictNullChecks is true.

If several methods depend on a value not being null, each one should check that value and throw an exception if it is null. It would be nice to extract that null check into a helper method, rather than duplicating it everywhere. However, if we do so, we can't get type checking on the value within each method.

For example, without extracting the null check:

```
class FooClass {
  public foo: number | null = null;

  public thisNeedsFooToNotBeNull(): void {
    if (this.foo === null) {
      throw new Error('foo should not be null');
    }
    doStuff(this.foo);
  }
}

function doStuff(foo: number) {
  console.log(`foo is ${foo}`);
}
```

With extracting:

```
class FooClass {
  public foo: number | null = null;

  private validateFoo(): void {
    if (this.foo === null) {
      throw new Error('foo should not be null');
    }
  }


  public thisNeedsFooToNotBeNull(): void {
    this.validateFoo();
    doStuff(this.foo);
  }
}

function doStuff(foo: number) {
  console.log(`foo is ${foo}`);
}
```

In the second version, we get TypeScript errors on the `doStuff(this.foo);` line, saying:

```
Argument of type 'number | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number' ts(2345)
```

Is there a way to get TypeScript to handle this kind of type checking extraction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When TypeScript 3.7 comes out it will feature [the `asserts` modifier](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695) which allows you to mark `void`-returning functions as type assertions, similarly to how [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) allow you to mark `boolean`-returning functions as type checks.

So pretty soon (or right now if you install `typescript@next`) you should be able to annotate `validateFoo()` like this:

```
private validateFoo(): asserts this is { foo: number } {
  if (this.foo === null) {
    throw new Error('foo should not be null')
  }
}
```

Here we're saying that the call to `validateFoo()` returns `asserts this is { foo: number }`, meaning that if `validateFoo()` returns at all, it will narrow `this` from `FooClass` (whose `foo` property is `number | null`), to `this & { foo: number }`, which means the `foo` property will not be `null`.

The rest of your code should compile as expected:

```
public thisNeedsFooToNotBeNull(): void {
  this.validateFoo();
  doStuff(this.foo); // no error now
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.7-Beta#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28DC4rQN4ChrQA4FcAjEAS2GgDNEAuaAO3wFtCBTAJ2gB978QRoAvDz4BubHjYkAbmAAuLaDNIATOSwTwAFAEpakCO1kxZACxIxzGSjR7N20AL4ZxOEhWibT5gHRV4ggSEGPm1nHHDoUzZ4AHd6FjiAUTZotk0Acj9oCBN4XmV6eFloVmEQdO0xCIdxGsxxAmIySLMIADkWFmUIDQAVeDaigCEWNt4QHVopeBICrAivCG8lWbUNHSrw5XgAZVl8CgpPVt9EStrMOop8OmBZEng6aG29g6O-WgY7NlD56GBHhB4CAWN4QPAAOaaAAGWUsABJ0H4HNDzg4gA)